# yum error on setools-console on Centos 7.3

Tags: centos, rpm, centos7, yum

Trying to install  setools-console-3.3.8-1.1.el7

yum install setools-console-3.3.8-1.1.el7

getting the following error

```
Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.


Error downloading packages:
  setools-console-3.3.8-1.1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

When I run yum list available I can see the package

```
$ yum list available | grep setools-console
setools-console.x86_64                    3.3.8-1.1.el7
```

How to resolve this issue?

Update 1:

```
$ yum list setools-console
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: denver.gaminghost.co
 * extras: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
 * updates: centos.gbeservers.com
Available Packages
setools-console.x86_64                                                                                        3.3.8-1.1.el7                                                                                         base
```

Comment: can you show the full output of this command: `]$ yum list setools-console`

Comment: @iamauser updated

Comment: It looks like you have some issues with your repo config - can you update the question with the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d` please. `setools-console` should be provided by the `base` repo.